# MYSQL Selecting all grouped rows except when group exceeds the limit of 1 000 000 records

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

can anyone suggest how to write a query which selects all grouped rows except those rows that together as a group exceed a limit (e.g. 1mil rows)? So the select should stop before a group starts if it's going to exceed.

Comment: The same way that you'd select all grouped rows except those rows that together as a group exceed a limit of 5. With that in mind, see: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of way to do exactly what you have in mind.  But, would there be anything wrong with just using a `HAVING` clause to assert that a matching group contains less than one million records?  Something like this:

```
SELECT col1, col2, SUM(col3) AS total
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY col1, col2
HAVING COUNT(*) < 1000000;
```